# why my program failed to be accepted just because I reverse the order of &&-conditinos of loop?

Tags: c

I want to find where the leading zero ends in a string? but a unexpected problems happened...

```
for(i=2980;(bin[i]==0)&&(i>=0);i--);//this failed to past 
for(i=2980;i>=0&&bin[i]==0;i--);//this is accepted by testing-web
```

but I think this two expressions have the same meaning..I can't find the reason ,please help me, thank you.

Comment: Because it will look at `bin[-1]` before evaluating if `i>=0`...

Comment: It's nitpicky, but the lack of whitespace in your code does not make it more efficient or faster. It just makes it harder to read. Also, the parens then become unnecessary on the condition. `bin[i] == && i >= 0` is equivalent to `(bin[i]==0)&&(i>=0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think this two expressions have the same meaning

They do not.  They differ.

`a && b` is a "short-circuit" evaluation.
If `a` is *false*, `b` is not evaluated.
If `a` is *true*, then `b` is evaluated.

Consider what happens when `i == -1`:

```
// Only (-1 >= 0) evaluated
// Since it was false bin[-1]==0 was not attempted.
(i >= 0) && (bin[i]==0)

// Code first tries bin[-1], which is outside the array bin[]
// Result: undefined behavior (UB).
// In OP's case, program failed.
(bin[i]==0) && (i>=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at how the for loop works...

Let's say i is 0:

```
for (i=2980; (bin[i]==0)&&(i>=0);i--)
```

Replacing i with 0 gives:

```
for (i=2980; (bin[0]==0)&&(0>=0);i--)
```

This is OK because 0 is a valid index. It then runs i-- and now i == -1 and it runs the `for` loop again:

```
for (i=2980; (bin[-1]==0)&&(-1>=0);i--)
```

So -1 is an invalid index. Swapping those two operations around "short circuits" the check and because `(-1>=0)` fails, it never runs `bin[-1]==0`.